# nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, grunt-nodemon

**EDIT**
After further testing, I have found that this is happening with both gulp and grunt on this app and on the default install of mean.js.  I'm running this locally on a Mac.  When I running either app using "node server.js" they don't crash.

I'm using a MEAN stack with grunt-nodemon and node is crashing when an express URL is accessed.  It isn't always consistent though.  Sometimes it works, sometimes node crashes right when the URL is hit retiring no data, and other times I get a response and node crashed immediately after.

**Browser console response:**

```
http://localhost:8000/api/users net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

**Terminal output:**

```
Mongoose: users.insert({ firstname: 'mike', lastname: 'jones', email:'mike@gmail.com', role: 'admin', password: 'mike', _id: ObjectId("57485c16fc11894b96c28057"), created: new Date("Fri, 27 May 2016 14:39:18 GMT"), __v: 0 })   
user.save success
node crash
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

In this case, the POST request went through, the user was added, then node crashed, but sometimes it crashes before a successful POST.  Node also occasionally crashes on the GET request.

**gruntfile.js:**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    var pkg = grunt.file.readJSON('package.json');

    var options = {
        paths: {
            app: 'app',
            assets: 'app/assets',
            dist: 'app/dist',
            distAssets: 'app/dist/assets',
            html: 'app/html',
            htmlTmp: '.tmp/htmlsnapshot',
            htmlAssets: 'app/html/assets',
            index: 'app/dist/index.html',
            indexDev: 'app/index.html',
            indexTmp: '.tmp/html/index.html'
        },
        pkg: pkg,
        env: {
            test: {
                NODE_ENV: 'test'
            },
            dev: {
                NODE_ENV: 'development'
            },
            prod: {
                NODE_ENV: 'production'
            }
        }
    };

    // Load grunt configurations automatically
    var configs = require('load-grunt-configs')(grunt, options);

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig(configs);

    // Connect to the MongoDB instance and load the models
    grunt.task.registerTask('mongoose', 'Task that connects to the MongoDB instance and loads the application models.', function () {
        // Get the callback
        var done = this.async();

        // Use mongoose configuration
        var mongoose = require('./config/lib/mongoose.js');

        // Connect to database
        mongoose.connect(function (db) {
            done();
        });
    });

    grunt.registerTask('bumper', ['bump-only']);
    grunt.registerTask('css', ['sass']);
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'sass',
        'copy:dev',
        'nodemon',
        'concurrent:dev',
        'watch',
        'mongoose'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('shared', [
        'clean:demo',
        'copy:demo',
        'sass',
        'ngconstant',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concat:generated',
        'cssmin:generated',
        'uglify:generated',
        'filerev',
        'usemin',
        'imagemin',
        'usebanner'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('demo', [
        'shared',
        'copy:postusemin',
        'grep:demo'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('dist', [
        'shared',
        'copy:postusemin',
        'copy:dist',
        'grep:dist',
        'compress',
        'copy:postusemin',
        'grep:demo',
    ]);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-forever');

};
```

**default.js**

```
module.exports.tasks = {
    // version update
    bump: {
        options: {
            files: ['package.json', 'bower.json'],
            pushTo: 'origin'
        }
    },

    // application constants
    ngconstant: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= paths.assets %>/js/app.constants.js',
            name: 'app.constants',
        }
    },

    // remove all bs from css
    cssmin: {
        options: {
            keepSpecialComments: 0
        }
    },
    markdown: {
        all: {
            files: [
                {
                    src: 'README.md',
                    dest: '<%= paths.assets %>/tpl/documentation.html'
                }
            ],
            options: {
                template: '<%= paths.assets %>/tpl/_documentation_template.html',
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**dev.js:**

```
var _ = require('lodash'),
defaultAssets = require('./assets/default'),
testAssets = require('./assets/test'),
testConfig = require('./env/test'),
fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path');

module.exports.tasks = {
    // copy files to correct folders
    copy: {
        dev: {
            files: [
                { expand: true, src: '**', cwd: '<%= paths.app %>/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts',                    dest: '<%= paths.assets %>/fonts' },
                { expand: true, src: '**', cwd: '<%= paths.app %>/bower_components/material-design-iconic-font/fonts',     dest: '<%= paths.assets %>/fonts' },
                { expand: true, src: '**', cwd: '<%= paths.app %>/bower_components/roboto-fontface/fonts',                 dest: '<%= paths.assets %>/fonts' },
                { expand: true, src: '**', cwd: '<%= paths.app %>/bower_components/weather-icons/font',                    dest: '<%= paths.assets %>/fonts' },
                { expand: true, src: '**', cwd: '<%= paths.app %>/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap', dest: '<%= paths.assets %>/fonts' }
            ]
        }
    },

    // watch for changes during development
    watch: {
        js: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js', '<%= paths.assets %>/js/**/*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
        css: {
            files: [
                '<%= paths.assets %>/css/**/*.scss'
            ],
            tasks: ['sass'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
        markdown: {
            files: [
                'README.md'
            ],
            tasks: ['markdown']
        },
        tasks:  [ 'express:dev' ],
    },

    // debug while developing
    jshint: {
        all: ['Gruntfile.js', '<%= paths.assets %>/js/**/*.js']
    },
    concurrent: {
        dev: {
            tasks: ['nodemon', 'node-inspector', 'watch'],
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            }
        }
    },
    nodemon: {
        dev: {
            script: 'server.js',
            options: {
                nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
                ext: 'js,html',
                callback: function (nodemon) {

                    nodemon.on('crash', function (event) {
                        console.log(event);
                    });


                },
                watch: _.union(defaultAssets.server.gruntConfig, defaultAssets.server.views, defaultAssets.server.allJS, defaultAssets.server.config)
            }
        }
    },
    forever: {
        server1: {
            options: {
                index: 'server.js',
                //logDir: 'logs'
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Angular controller function:**

```
  $scope.addUser = function(){

      var user = {
          firstname: $scope.firstname,
          lastname: $scope.lastname,
          email: $scope.email,
          role: $scope.role.selected,
          password: $scope.password
      };

      $http.post('/api/userAdd', user ).then(function successCallback(response) {
          $location.path('/users');
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
          console.log('error addding user');
          console.log(response);
      });
  };
```

**Express route:**

```
User = require('../models/user.js');

module.exports = function (app) {

    app.get('/api/users', function (req, res) {

        User.find({}, function (err, users) {
            if ( err ) {
                res.send({
                    message : 'error finding users',
                    success: false
                });
            } else {
                res.json(users);
            }
        });

    });

    app.get('/api/users', function (req, res) {
        User.find({fields: {}}, function (err, docs) {
            res.json(docs);
        });
    });

    app.post('/api/userAdd', function (req, res) {

        var user = new User(req.body);

        user.save( function( err, user ){

            if (err){
                console.log('user.save error');
                console.log(err);
                res.send({
                    success: false
                });
            } else {
                console.log('user.save success');
                res.send({
                    success: true
                });
            }
        });

    });

};
```

I'm also testing with Chromes Advanced REST extension and with any request using this tool node crashes immediately.

I'm new to MEAN so am I missing something here that is causing the crash?  Any ideas?

Comment: Try running your server manually and see if any errors get printed before it crashes: `node server.js`

Comment: Running manually seems to solve the problem, thank.  Does that mean I have some issue or misconfiguration with Grunt?

Comment: Not really. I assumed that by running it standalone, you would get to see _why_ it crashes. It wasn't supposed to work better that way ;D

Comment: Added the full gruntfile.js, default.js, and dev.js that are being used and cause the error.  Hoping that helps somehow.

Comment: Now testing with `node --debug server.js` I get the error message `Segmentation fault: 11` and node crashes.  But if I don't use `--debug` there is no crash and no error message

Answer (score 96):

This is happening because of all the running server processes in the background.
So all you need to do is stop them from the terminal.

Quick trick

---

**FOR LINUX**

**Kill them all by running this on terminal:**

```
pkill -f node
```

And then restart nodemon.

---

**FOR Windows**

```
 1. Go to the task manager
 2. Then look for Node.js: Server-side JavaScript
 3. Then right click on it and End task from the processes.
```

Then restart the server. It will work fine.

Comment: What to do on windows ?

Comment: For Linux: This did not work for me. I had to also use `px aux | grep node` and subsequently kill the processes using `kill -9 [PROCCESS_ID]`

Comment: "pkill -f node" doesn't work. What works is from the answer below: killall -9 node

Comment: I don't see "Node.js: Server-side JavaScript" in task manager on windows.

Comment: in windows, open powershell, and do "taskkill /im node.exe /f", thx for giving hint to kill node process

Answer (score 17):

for windows users, go to the task manager and then find for node.js server-side javascript, and end task on the process. then try again with your command.

Comment: I tried to kill the running server in the terminal with various commands...non worked but this simple trick did it. Thanks @Jamim Uddin.

Answer (score 11):

In the terminal using the below command to kill the existing running port and restart your service.

```
killall -9 node
```

or
to kill a particular port instead of all

```
sudo lsof -i :3000 //replace 3000 with your port number
sudo kill -9 31363 // replace 31363 with your PID
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Unlike "pkill -f node" from the answer above

Comment: How do you find the PID? I'm also on Linux.

Comment: @ShaneG sudo lsof -i :3000 (here 3000 is the port of your running application)
this will return below type of response
COMMAND     PID  USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
php     1159083 SIVA   11u  IPv4 8207821      0t0  TCP localhost:3000 (LISTEN)

here you can see the PID at second column here my PID for port 3000 is 1159083

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes it happenes when you forget to source your .env files

Comment: Thank you!  I'm sure you saved me from hours of additional hair pulling.

Answer (score 6):

***Issue :***  *app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...*

There could be different reasons:

**1. Running node in background**

`pkill -f node`

Worked in Mac OS ,did not work in Microsoft.

2.**Server.js and package.json are not in same folder** . Check it .

check package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     "start": "nodemon Server.js"
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I update node from v4.2.6 to v4.4.5 fixed the issue with the default mean.js install.  I'll build out from there.

Comment: I suggest you to switch to last node LTS version : 8.9.3. Or at least the last LTS node 4.x : 4.8.7. Easy move with nvm (https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your node daemon is still running.

`ps -eaf | grep node`

if it gives something like

`abhinav  15759 15748  0 19:30 pts/2    00:00:00 sh -c nodemon server.js
abhinav  15760 15759  0 19:30 pts/2    00:00:00 node /home/abhinav/Documents/Projects/WebD/Node/smartbrain/smart-brain-api/node_modules/.bin/nodemon server.js
abhinav  15812 15801  0 19:31 pts/2    00:00:00 sh -c nodemon server.js`

then try:

`killall node`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used `MongoDB` for more than a month. So it automatically paused the `MongoDB` cluster in the MongoDB cloud (atlas). I resumed the cluster and restart the application (along with a recheck of the mongo connection URL which was saved in default.json).

This is how it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case your PORT is used by previous node process(tasks)

Run command netstat -a -n -o | find "8080"
[image: cmd1]

And pass opened task using below command

taskkill /F /PID "1544"

[image: cmd2]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still experiencing this problem, you may want to check if the syntax is correct and all node options you're using are still supported.

For instance, I've had the following mistake:
*MongoParseError: options poolsize, usenewurlparse are not supported*
so I removed these parameters and the server runned - [here's the solution that worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acPjX.png)

The "App crashed" error mainly occurs because of syntax errors, so if you're struggling even after you restarted everything, make sure to check the syntax of your code as well as the version you're using for Node.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be because the MongoClient options you used are the deprecated ones.

For example, use `maxPoolSize` instead of `poolSize`, use `wtimeoutMS` instead of `wtimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the node version. Its always recommended to use a stable node version rather going for the latest version, which may create some issues while the program.
I updated the npm to the specific version -v14.16.7 for my app, by using the nvm install /
Note: You can use any version as your preference.

nvm is the node version manager. You can download it from :
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/release

nvm is mainly used for the version control of the node.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had wrong database port configured

Change DB_PORT to 8889 in `.env` file fixed it.

So there is possibility of wrong app configuration, behind crashing of app.

Answer (score 0):

This error might be comes when we pass other values then string in `response.send()`
if you pass some numeric value in `response.send(9)` then it gives error so, you can pass `response.send("9")`, `response.send` only allow to send string values

Answer (score 0):

- Stop the nodemon then
- Start again

**Note:** Killing the node task in windows Task Manager worked fine than simply stopping and starting the nodemon.

Answer (score -1):

This usually happens when you make changes to the server, while your server is running. For instead when you git pull to make changes to your server. Therefore, you need to kill the PID of the server that is running.

On windows you need to run the following commands:

```
> **netstat -ano|findstr "PID :3000"** // Replace 3000 with the port number
> **taskkill /pid 18264 /f** // Replace the 18264 with the pid number you received by running the first command
```

On Linux/Unix system you need to run the following commands:

```
> **lsof -i tcp:3000**
> **Kill -9 18264**
```

Answer (score -1):

```json
"scripts": {
   "start": "nodemon script.js"
}
```

Here, after `nodemon` write file name which you want to run like I have written `script.js` in `package.json`.

Answer (score -1):

Easier way to kill node.js services on Windows is simply to run this command in command prompt

```
taskkill /im node.exe /F
```

Answer (score -1):

verify mongo installation using `mongo` or `mongosh` in you command.

Answer (score -2):

I encountered this challenge when working on nexmo sms app.

To fix the crashing, go to your `app.js`. If you have these lines of code. Its normally on the very first lines...

```
`import { Socket } from 'dgram';`

`const express = require('express');`
`const bodyParser = require('body-parser');`
`const ejs = require('ejs');`
`const Nexmo = require('nexmo');`
`const socketio = require('socket.io');`
```

Simply delete/remove the first line of code
`import { Socket } from 'dgram';`

Leaving these ones...

```
    `const express = require('express');`
    `const bodyParser = require('body-parser');`
    `const ejs = require('ejs');`
    `const Nexmo = require('nexmo');`
    `const socketio = require('socket.io');`
```

and restart your application using "nodemon"

Comment: Why do you say add his and take this away? Why just not add it in the first place?

Answer (score -2):

This can happen with incorrect paths.

Example: If your `nodemon server.js` path is in `D:\Ex-Track\mern-exercise` but If you are didn't use the full path `D:\Ex-Track` in your grunt, this can cause nodemon to fail.

Comment: The answer is not clear and not formatted correctly.

Answer (score -2):

That works for me:

`[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`
means you changes the file exactly at the time you save (nodemon debugger) working, try to use history to go back your changes. just that. if your changes can not be back from history do these steps:

Delete your nodemon in your ROOT node module like in this picture

```
MacBook-Pro:/usr/local/lib$ cd node_modules/
MacBook-Pro:/usr/local/lib/node_modules$ ls
expo-cli/         npm/              react-native-cli/
nodemon/          react-devtools/
MacBook-Pro:/usr/local/lib/node_modules$ sudo rm -R n
nodemon/ npm/     
MacBook-Pro:/usr/local/lib/node_modules$ sudo rm -R nodemon/
MacBook-Pro:/usr/local/lib/node_modules$
```

then install nodmon again.

Answer (score -2):

This is my error:
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

My answer: Make sure that we:
1- install bcrypt:

```sh
npm install bcrypt-nodejs
```

2- defined bcrypt:

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
```