# MailChimp - Nodemon didn't send to Failure page

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mailchimp, nodemon

I am trying to deploy my signup web app using MailChimp. However, when I tried to run on port 3000. everytime that it succeeds it will send to success.html but when it's a failure, it suppose to send to failure.html however, it still send to success.html and also sometimes I get [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

please help clarify what I did wrong with my code. Thank you so much. I really appreciate this

the below codes are in app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mailchimp = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing');
const https = require("https");
const request = require("request");

mailchimp.setConfig({
    apiKey: "d7a44647dc9eccdf9ac0ba24c4f38649-us21",
    server: "us21",
  });

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

const port = 3000;

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

async function add(member) {
    const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember("18eb2787d5", member);
};

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const emailAddress = req.body.email;

    const newMember = {
        email_address: emailAddress,
        status: "subscribed",
        merge_fields: {
            FNAME: firstName,
            LNAME: lastName
        }
    };

    add(newMember);

    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
    } else {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
    }
});

app.post("/failure", function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/");
})



app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log(`This server is running on port ${port}!`);
})


// My API Key
// d7a44647dc9eccdf9ac0ba24c4f38649-us21

// List ID
// 18eb2787d5
```

the below codes are in failure.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Failure</title>
        
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="pain" class="col-12 mt-5 pt-5">
            <img src="./images/fail.JPG">
        </div>
        <form id="makeItCenter" class="tryAgain" action="index.html" method="post">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning mt-3" type="submit">Try again</button>
        </form>
        <p id="makeItCenter" class="mt-2 mb-3 text-body-secondary">&copy; Trisha Supannopaj</p>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the below codes are in success.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Success</title>
        
        <!-- <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="pain" class="col-12 mt-5 pt-5">
            <img src="./images/success.JPG">
        </div>
        <p id="makeItCenter" class="mt-2 mb-3 text-body-secondary">&copy; Trisha Supannopaj</p>
        <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

the below codes are in index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="auto">
  <head>
    

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.112.5">
    <title>Signup</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/sign-in/">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>


  <body class="d-flex align-items-center py-4 bg-body-tertiary">
    <div id="pain" class="col-12">
    <div class="row flex-lg-row-reverse align-items-center g-5 py-5">
      <div class="col-10 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
        <img src="./images/songcard.jpg" class="d-block mx-lg-auto img-fluid" alt="Bootstrap Themes" width="95%" height="95%" loading="lazy">
      </div>
      <main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto">
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <div id="makeItCenter">
                <img class="mb-2 mt-5" src="./images/avata.PNG" alt="" width="40%" height="40%">
            </div>
            <h1 id="makeItCenter" class="h4 mb-3 fw-normal">Signup Here!</h1>
            
            <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-1" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-1" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control mb-1" placeholder="Email Address" required>
            </div>
    
            <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 py-2" type="submit">Sign Me Up!</button>
            <p id="makeItCenter" class="mt-2 mb-3 text-body-secondary">&copy; Trisha Supannopaj</p>
        </form>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>


        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486631/nodemon-app-crashed-waiting-for-file-changes-before-starting)