# Cant find Node.js: Server-side in task manager

Tags: discord, discord.js, nodemon

I'm relatively new to Python and have encountered an error that has me stumped. Upon digging into the issue, I've hit a roadblock in my attempts to resolve it.

The error message is: "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..."

In my search for a solution, I stumbled upon a helpful post on Stack Overflow ([nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486631/nodemon-app-crashed-waiting-for-file-changes-before-starting)), which seemed to address my problem. However, upon checking the Task Manager, I was unable to locate what it was talking about.

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I was following a youtube video and it said that by running nodemon it will allow my discord bot to automatically update

Comment: Why is this tagged with `python` if the problem is `nodemon`, which is a node task runner? Also, nodemon is not "its own executable", it's not going to show up as nodemon in task manager: turn on the `command line` column and look for whichever `Node.js JavaScript Runtime` process was started to run nodemon.

Comment: Sorry about that im still new to coding like i stated above and new to stack overflow

Comment: Hey Mike I just did what you said and I did find Node.js JavaScript Runtime under the Visual studio tab in my task manager. I ended the task and when i entered nodemon into  it again it gave me the same error. 
Am i doing something wrong? Let me know please always willing to learn!

Comment: Not with the description you currently have, unfortunately. Give the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit] your post to explain what you're _actually_ doing, in a way that lists all the steps involved so that someone else can run through those same steps and (ideally) reproduce your problem. Right now we don't even know whether you're _actually_ running nodemon because there's no code/command line calls to that effect in your post.

Comment: Ok so do you recommend I make a new post about this but with the code I have and the error message?

Comment: No, click [edit] and just edit your post to include all the details necessary for someone else to understand and ideally reproduce the problem =)